# Grub and getting into Real Mode (low-level assembly language programming)

Tags: assembly, x86, grub, real-mode

I've been working on a toy OS and have been using grub as my boot loader.  Recently when trying to use VGA I found that I couldn't use hardware interrupts.  This I found was because I had been slung into protected mode by grub.

Does anybody know how to get back into real mode without having to get rid of grub?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use real mode BIOS / VESA calls from GRUB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747574/how-to-use-real-mode-bios-vesa-calls-from-grub)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GRUB as your boot loader you could use the `intcall` (as specified in the [COMBOOT API](http://syslinux.zytor.com/comboot.php)) to call BIOS function int 0x10 in your case to access the [VESA VBE](http://www.vesa.org/public/VBE/vbe3.pdf).

But this will not help if you need to access the VGA hardware registers.

Answer (score 1):

you mean writeport(value,$3c9)?

```
>mov 03c9,AH
>out value,AL
```

or similar in INTEL asm(NASM)

3c9
3c8
IIRC are VGA registers.